# mySQL table design for facebook style posts that suits one-to-many or many-to-many

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, one-to-many

I am trying to build / design a table that will serve purpose to a post/comment system similar to google+ that can support bidirectional one-to-many/many-to-many relations. What I have currently is

```
member_id, 
post_id, 
post_body, 
post_date, 
post_flagged, 
post_shared, 
post_likes
```

- member_id = my members id's
- post_id = my auto increment column to give each post a unique id
- post_body = the actual post
- post_flagged = part of a moderation system I intend on building later
- post_shared = some form of grouping id's (not sure how this will work but think
  google+ circles)
- post_likes = grouped member_id's of who likes the post.

I have a comment table thats pretty much the same as the above except it has a comment_id on top of the ones above listed to server as its auto incriminate column.

What I am ultimately seeking here currently is I guess a sanity check. Does the above construct/schema look like it might work? would you add/remove/alter it in any way? If not/or if so. Can anyone also suggest what might be a good way to do the post_shared column? Is there some type of object or means of storing data in that column that would serve purpose to the logic of Google+ Circles?

Comment: If you are going to do it like Facebook, you may want to store more detail as to WHO liked/shared/flagged the post. These would probably each necessitate their own tables, similar to the comment table. Possibly even another table for liked/flagged comments.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by many-to-many posts? Do you mean the ability to re-post/share posts?

Comment: @MartinBean I might one day want to go the distance and allow re-posting of a post but not right now.

Comment: @Travesty3 there are separate tables for the liked, shared, flagged that contain the specifics of each (except the liked, im thinking just user id's will be sufficient for that for my needs at least.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, your `post_shared` column is what is really in question here. Let's say you have a post that is directed at 5 "circles" (we will steal this term from Google). How would you indicate that in your current setup?

The only way to do this in one field is something like `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` where those numbers are the circle id's. This isn't a very good practice.

The best way I can see to accomplish this would be to have this schema:

- Posts: `post_id, post_body, post_flagged, post_likes`
- Circles: `circle_id, ...`
- PostCircles: `post_id, circle_id`

The PostCircles table will show which posts are visible to which circles. In the example above, you have 5 rows in the PostCircles table. Let's say the post id is 1:

```
post_id    |    circle_id
1               1
1               2
1               3
1               4
1               5
```

Then you can use your query language to show display the appropriate posts, depending on which circles the viewer is in (note the user schema is not shown in this answer).

Comment: I should have elaborated I do have a "Circles" table where the schema is group_id, label (for display only), member_id (the actual member the group_id belongs to), and friends (where the thought for thought for that was "1:2:3:4:5" and these are the actual friends who'd be allowed to see said post)

Comment: My issue is as you said though the post_shared. Ultimately my goal is to take the concept of the circles and apply it to my own needs, where I can share with one or more circles so to speak or a circle and specific person(s)

Comment: Okay - well that is the problem that my post solves. You will want a PostCircles table, or something similar, that relates the `post_id` of the Posts table to the `group_id` of the Groups table (or Circles table, whatever you are calling it).

Answer (score 1):

post_shared should not be in the main post table.

for a normalized solution, you would want a `circles` table, a `users` table, a `posts` table and some associative tables to tell which ones are related - something like

```
user_circles
post_circles
```